# I want to get the value of elements on a dynamically created div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I'm trying to get the value of multiple dropboxes that are created by cloning a whole div using jQuery

```
<div style="display: inline-block;" class="col-md-12" id="TIDiv">
  <label>TI's</label>
  <div id="TItoClone" class="TI">
    &nbsp;<asp:DropDownList ID="TIDropD1" class="TIDropD" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" CssClass="btn btn-default btn-sm col-lg-8" DataTextField="nombreNom" DataValueField="IdNom" Style="width: 270px;"></asp:DropDownList>

    <a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm removeTI" style="margin-top: 1%;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a>
    <br />
    <br />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-12"><a class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm addTIBtn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>Agregar TI</a></div>
```

I clone them using:

```
$('body').on('click', '.addTIBtn', function () {
  var clonedNorm = $('#TIToClone').clone();
  $('.TIDropD', clonedNorm).attr('id', 'TIDropD' + indexTI);
  $('#TIDiv').append(clonedNorm);
  indexTI++;
});
```

I would like to get the selected values from the dropboxes to an array using jQuery

I already tried with this:

```
$(".TIDropD").each(function () {
  subcatIDs.push($(this).val());
});

$('[id^=TIDropD]').each(function (i, item) {
  var grade = $(item).val();
  alert(grade);
});
```

But it doesn't seem to work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use event delegation: https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Answer (score 0):

I know you're using `asp:Dropdown` but I tried to do the same behavior in static html to give you an idea how to do it, hope this helps how to do it. if I miss understand any part of your question please leave a comment!

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

   
    $(".addTIBtn").click( function () {
            var htmlf = $("#TItoClone").html()
            $('#TIDiv').append(htmlf);

        });

    subcatIDs = [];
   
    $(".TIDropD").each(function (i, val) {
                subcatIDs.push($(val).val());
    });

    console.log(subcatIDs);
         
  
  
  
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="display: inline-block;" class="col-md-12" id="TIDiv">
                <label>TI's</label>
                <div id="TItoClone" class="TI">
                    &nbsp;<select ID="TIDropD1" class="TIDropD" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" CssClass="btn btn-default btn-sm col-lg-8" DataTextField="nombreNom" DataValueField="IdNom" Style="width: 270px;">
                    <option value="1" selected=selected>test1</option>
                    <option value="2" >test2</option>
</select>

                    <a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm removeTI" style="margin-top: 1%;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a>
                    <br />
                    <br />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12"><a class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm addTIBtn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>Agregar TI</a></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding body to each element should work when you create dynamically an element

```
$('body').on('click', '.addTIBtn', function () {
  var clonedNorm = $('body #TIToClone').clone();
  $('body .TIDropD', clonedNorm).attr('id', 'TIDropD' + indexTI);
  $('body #TIDiv').append(clonedNorm);
  indexTI++;
});
```